# Talend Open Studio for Data Integration show error when creating metadata

Tags: java, talend

I have a problem when using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration 6.0. 
My environment is Windows 7 64-bit, Java 1.8. When I create Metadata from a delimited file or an Excel file it always shows an error like this in the preview section:

```
錯誤: 找不到或無法載入主要類別 b.shadowfileinputtodelimitedoutput_0_1.ShadowFileInputToDelimitedOutput

Preview error. Some settings must be changed.
Note: Preview errors are generally due to a wrong encoding setting.
org.talend.designer.runprocess.shadow.ShadowFilePreview.preview(ShadowFilePreview.java:90)
org.talend.metadata.managment.ui.utils.ShadowProcessHelper.getCsvArray(ShadowProcessHelper.java:383)
org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.files.delimited.DelimitedFileStep2Form$PreviewProcessor.nonUIProcessInThread(DelimitedFileStep2Form.java:1309)
org.talend.commons.ui.swt.thread.SWTUIThreadProcessor$1.run(SWTUIThreadProcessor.java:74)
```

and when I try to run the job the same error occurs:

```
Starting job ds at 16:21 28/08/2015.
錯誤: 找不到或無法載入主要類別 b.ds_0_1.ds
Job ds ended at 16:21 28/08/2015. [exit code=1]
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

May be Talend has problem ton interpret asiatic character, have tried with only "occidendal" caracters in your delimited file or an Excel file (and saved in UTF-8) ?

Comment: Hi Guymage, I tried with Talend Studio 5.6.2 its works fine but I need use talend Studio 6.0 because they have kafka palette on it. And My delimited file is not asiatic characther. my csv file is like this MappingType,TYPE,SITE,LANG_ID,SOURCE,TRANSLATION_ID,TRANSLATION
MULTI_LANGUAGE,ErrorCode,Default,en,error,9,Error 9 test
MULTI_LANGUAGE,ErrorCode,Default,en,error,10,Error 10 test
MULTI_LANGUAGE,ErrorCode,Default,en,error,11,Error 11 test.

Comment: my encoding file is ANSI. I found that the main problem with my Talend studio is it can't generate .class file. so every time I run the job or to create metadata it's always says that couldn't load class or no class found error message. I don't know if this problem is a bug or there is problem with my environment. If anyone have some clue please help me. Thanks